# Getting google token for Blazor WASM

Tags: jwt, blazor, google-oauth, google-api-dotnet-client

I have Blazor WASM client app where all authorization flow is based on JWT token obtained from API by user & password authentication.  I would like to add Google authentication as well so that google token would be sent to API and after verification client would get back JWT token

how can I get google token using using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2 library in Blazor WASM project.